# Vertical alignment CSS not aligning

Tags: vertical-alignment

I am experiencing a problem with vertical alignment with products on the vape site I'm working on, I can't seem to align the products, reason being mainly is because description length, star rating and price/sale differ by up to 3 lines.

Ideally I would like to align:

> top of pics

And

> add to cart/choose options

not just one or the other as it is right now.

Here is the [vape site](https://www.lunar-vape.com/product-category/e-liquid/) I'm working on.

Would anyone be able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

In the div with the classes `box-text box-text-products text-center grid-style-2` I would add another class or add the following to the box-text class.

```
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
```

Then add `align-self:end` to the div's with classes `price-wrapper` & `add-to-cart-button`.  You might also need to make sure that the overall containing div is set to height of 100%, I think it is the div with the class of `col-inner`. If you have more questions about using css grid you can refer to [CSS Trick Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).